# Dynamic form generation for inputs_for doesn't create unique list of form elements

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework, has-many

I’ve been doing some research on `inputs_for` and I’ve come across an issue with generating forms from a list.  I was wondering if anyone had any insight, suggestions or previous experience with this issue:

My relationship structure is:

- Shopping Cart

  - Items

My schemas are

```
schema "shopping_cart" do
  has_many :items, Item, on_delete: :delete_all
  timestamps()
end

schema "items" do
  field :quantity, :integer
  belongs_to :shopping_cart, ShoppingCart
  timestamps()
end
```

I’m attempting to iterate over a list of @items inside of a form

```
form_for @changeset, Routes.order_path(@conn, :review), fn f ->
   render(View, "_form.html", Map.merge(assigns, %{f: f}))
end
```

_form.html --->

```
<%= for item <- @items do %>
  <%= inputs_for @f, :items, fn sci -> %>
    <%= number_input sci[![enter image description here][1]][1], :quantity, value: @item.quantity %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any inputs generated will have the same name, which means Phoenix will see it as one form param like:

```
"items" => %{"0" => %{"quantity" => "1122"}}
```

Below you can find an image of the HTML names and here is the JS solution I used to basically rename the inputs.  (It grabs data from elixir and does the renaming to each element.

```
window.Gon.getAsset('items').forEach(function(item) {
     let element = document.getElementById("input-quantity-" + item.id)
     element.name = `order[order_items][${item.id}][quantity]`
});
```

Is this expected behaviour? I feel like the JS solution is a sloppy hack that might come back later to bite me in the butt.
Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: When I have to do this in Phoenix, I just stop using the "input helpers".
See this example: https://github.com/peaceful-james/invoicer/blob/8e09c1ffa7c557fcb40b57ed6eb4016936880844/apps/invoicer_html/lib/invoicer_html/live/home.html.leex#L100 where I create checkboxes in a loop. I think you should do something like this but for number inputs. It gives you more control. So, maybe stop using `number_input` and just use normal HTML `<input>`.

Comment: @PeacefulJames I want to shape params a certain way.  To do that, I think I need to use the form objects, plus theyre really useful.